# Cytoscape.js animates out of viewport before returning

Tags: javascript, animation, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to smoothly animate from a rendered position at one zoom level, to a rendered position at another zoom level, with all the graph elements staying within the viewport?

Here is a jsbin demonstrating my problem. After the large graph loads, click one of the nodes and notice how it animates off-screen and then on-screen. (You'll need the viewport to be narrow enough.)

https://jsbin.com/mimesam/9/edit?js,output

Is there a way around this? I really would like layout animations to work by default so that `fit` (zoom/pan) is taken into account *during* the layout animation, so that layout-fitted rendered positions animate smoothly to each other.

Description: start with a graph of a couple hundred elements. Use a layout to generate initial positions. Use a viewport that is small enough that the model positions are too large for the viewport, so that `fit` causes a zoom.

Then pick a subset of the graph, and invoke the same `fit` layout on that subset.

Ideally, the subset of the graph should smoothly animate in one direction, from the original position to the new position.

Instead, I see swoopy behavior, where the elements animate out of the viewport on their way to the model positions, before the fit kicks in and animates back to the zoomed rendered positions.

Comment: I think it is because you remove elements suddenly without any animation. Maybe you can hide them instead of removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Try making things step by step and animated

```
cy.animate({
  fit: { eles: cy.$() },
  duration: 500,
  complete: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      cy.layout({
        name: 'breadthfirst',
        animationDuration: 2000,
        animate: true,
        fit: true,
        directed: true,
      }).run();
    }, 500);
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a good thought and I've tried it. It improves the situation, but when the layout kicks in it still expands with some elements going past viewport edge. Effects depend on size of viewport, size of subgraph, size of overall graph.

Comment: Layout some nodes go out of sight for a small amount of time. Do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, they go one direction, past the viewport edge, and then come back in the other direction and eventually settle into place.

Comment: @tunesmith if you set `padding: 130,` inside layout options, it doesn't happen. It is about the animation of the layout algorithm

Comment: `padding: 130` is an arbitrary value that only works for this particular graph and a particular panel width. `130` doesn't work for me on my screen. `200` does, but the cost is that the end position has way too much padding. It's sort of like how just having a large enough viewport size would make the problem go away too. The question is more a general question about how to smoothly animate from fit rendered position to fit rendered position, without the animation temporarily exceeding viewport size, in all cases.

Comment: Then all your problem is about the animation inside the layout.

Comment: Yes, it appears so. I created an issue with cytoscapejs and we are starting to discuss a feature change. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2966 Not sure I have the time or JS skills to add the feature but I will try.