# Animate along curved/bezier path edge, or self-referential edge, in Cytoscape?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Consider the following `test.html` (based on https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-cola/demo-compound.html - except I've used bezier lines for the edges)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-cola.js demo (compound)</title>

  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
  <!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-cola/cytoscape-cola.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #cy {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    h1 {
      opacity: 0.5;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),

        layout: {
          name: 'cola'
        },

        style: [
          {
            selector: 'node',
            css: {
              'background-color': '#f92411',
              'content': 'data(id)',
            }
          },

          {
            selector: 'node:parent',
            css: {
              'background-opacity': 0.333
            }
          },

          {
            selector: 'edge',
            css: {
              'line-color': '#f92411',
              'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
              'control-point-weights': '0.25 0.75',
              'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
              'target-arrow-color': '#f92411',
              'arrow-scale': 2.0,
            }
          }
        ],

        elements: [{ group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n0' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n2' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n3' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n4', parent: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n5' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n6' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n7', parent: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n8', parent: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n9', parent: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n10', parent: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n11', parent: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n12' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n13' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n14' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n15' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n16' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n17' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n18' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n19' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n20' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n21' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n22' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n23' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n24', parent: 'n39' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n25', parent: 'n39' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n26', parent: 'n42' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n27', parent: 'n42' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n28', parent: 'n42' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n29', parent: 'n40' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n30', parent: 'n40' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n31', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n32', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n33', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n34', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n35', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n36', parent: 'n41' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n39', parent: 'n43' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n40', parent: 'n42' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n41', parent: 'n42' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n42', parent: 'n43' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n43' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n44', parent: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n45', parent: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n46', parent: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e1', source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e2', source: 'n2', target: 'n3' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e3', source: 'n0', target: 'n3' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e4', source: 'n1', target: 'n4' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e5', source: 'n2', target: 'n4' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e6', source: 'n4', target: 'n5' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e7', source: 'n5', target: 'n6' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e8', source: 'n4', target: 'n6' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e9', source: 'n4', target: 'n7' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e10', source: 'n7', target: 'n8' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e11', source: 'n8', target: 'n9' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e12', source: 'n7', target: 'n9' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e13', source: 'n13', target: 'n14' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e14', source: 'n12', target: 'n14' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e15', source: 'n14', target: 'n15' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e16', source: 'n14', target: 'n16' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e17', source: 'n15', target: 'n17' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e18', source: 'n17', target: 'n18' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e19', source: 'n18', target: 'n19' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e20', source: 'n17', target: 'n20' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e21', source: 'n19', target: 'n20' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e22', source: 'n16', target: 'n20' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e23', source: 'n20', target: 'n21' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e24', source: 'n22', target: 'n24' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e25', source: 'n23', target: 'n24' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e26', source: 'n24', target: 'n25' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e27', source: 'n26', target: 'n38' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e28', source: 'n26', target: 'n37' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e29', source: 'n26', target: 'n39' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e30', source: 'n26', target: 'n27' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e31', source: 'n26', target: 'n28' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e32', source: 'n26', target: 'n40' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e33', source: 'n21', target: 'n31' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e34', source: 'n21', target: 'n32' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e35', source: 'n31', target: 'n33' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e36', source: 'n31', target: 'n34' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e37', source: 'n33', target: 'n34' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e38', source: 'n32', target: 'n35' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e39', source: 'n32', target: 'n36' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e40', source: 'n16', target: 'n40' } },
        { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e41', source: 'n46', target: 'n46' } },
        ]
      });

      document.getElementById('btn-zoom-along-line').onclick = function() {
        //let first_node = cy.nodes('[id = "n16"]')[0];
        let edge_to_zoom_along = cy.edges('[id = "e30"]')[0];
        let first_node = edge_to_zoom_along.source();
        let second_node = edge_to_zoom_along.target();
        cy.fit(first_node, 30);
        cy.animate({ // https://stackoverflow.com/q/70678336
          fit: {
            eles: second_node, padding: 20 },
          },
          {
            duration: 1000
          }
        );

      }
    }); // end DOMContentLoaded
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-cola demo (compound)</h1>
  <button type="button" id="btn-zoom-along-line">Do zoom along line</button>
  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you run this snippet, wait for the placement to "settle" and then click on "Do zoom along line". Here I've chosen edge `{ id: 'e30', source: 'n26', target: 'n27' }` to serve as the "line" to go along to - so when clicking "Do zoom along line", it will first zoom with `cy.fit` on the source (here n26), and then try to animate to `cy.fit` the target (to n27) - which ultimately has the effect, as if the camera is panning in straight line from n26 to n27. However, the edge connecting these is Bezier - curved. So, my first question is:

1. How can I animate the "camera" panning, from focusing on one node to focusing to another, while following along the curved edge that connects these edges?

Note also, I have a self-referential edge: `{ id: 'e41', source: 'n46', target: 'n46' }` - and it did get rendered:

[image: self-referential edge]

... however it starts from north, and then bends westward, and so it overlaps with node n45. So:

2. Is there a way to specify in cytoscape, that a self-referential edge should start at a specific position (e.g. node "north"), and then bend in a specific way (say by specifying end anchor being the same node "east")?

And talking of self-referential edges, the above code which animates between `cy.fit` of one source node and `cy.fit` of another target node will never work, since source and target node will be the same. So:

3. How can I animate camera panning along a self-referential curved/Bezier edge in Cytoscape?